# Android system app conversion

Tags: android, security

I have made a security app that can locate your phone. For rooted phones I have made it possible to convert it to a system app so it will survive a factory reset. I currently use this code to convert the app:

```
mount -o remount, rw /system
cat /data/app/com.androidlost-1.apk > /system/app/com.androidlost.apk
chmod 644 /system/app/com.androidlost.apk
mount -o remount,ro /system
reboot
```

and that works just fine since all apk files are located in the directory /data/app/

But on my latest android phone the package is now stored in a directory, a subdirectory called lib and the apk file is renamed to base.apk:

```
/data/app/com.androidlost-1/base.apk
/data/app/com.androidlost-1/lib/
```

1. How do I convert this new type of package installation to a system app?
2. Is there an easy way to detect what kind of package system is used?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there were no simple way to do this I just do it the hard way:

1. I create directories with the mkdir command and then copies
2. Use the packagemanager to see if the apk contains the string base.apk to determine how the apks are stored

So a lot if statements and system commands.